# Adding two numbers as linked lists

Tags: c++, linked-list

I am trying to add two numbers (represented as linked-lists with numbers in reverse order). I have a solution in C++

```cpp
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
        bool carry = 0;
        ListNode *head1 = l1; 
        ListNode *head2 = l2; 

        ListNode *head = nullptr;
        ListNode *curr = nullptr;

        while (head1 || head2 || carry) {
            // get value
            int val = (head1 ? head1->val : 0) +
                (head2 ? head2->val : 0) + carry;

            curr = new ListNode(val % 10);
            if (!head) head = curr;

            curr = curr->next;
            head1 = head1 ? head1->next : nullptr; 
            head2 = head2 ? head2->next : nullptr;
            carry = val / 10;
        }

        return head;
    }
};
```

For some reason this will only return a linkedlist of length one. Shouldnt this initialize head to curr the first time, and then curr will continue building the list properly?

Comment: Consider: Where do you store the newly allocated node for the second digit (that would make a list of length 2)?

Comment: The first time round the loop, you create curr, get head to point to it then you move curr on to curr->next which will be null, so it will never add any more to the list that head points to

Comment: To get a linked list longer than size 1, a node's "next" pointer needs to be set at some point. Which line of code sets the `next` field of a node?

Comment: So initially, head points to curr, which is allocated, and the correct value. Then curr moves to `curr->next` (which is null). Then the loop continues and will set curr to a new ListNode. So shouldnt we have head pointing to curr, which was allocated properly, and now `curr->next` has also been allocated? Thus, the second digit should be stores in `curr->next` so we should have curr->(curr->next) with head pointing to curr

Comment: @Iza If you have `int a = 1; int b = a; b = 3;`, what do you expect the end value of `a` to be? Is it set to `3` because the value of `b` changed? (It's not.) Which line of your example code sets the `next` field of a node?

Answer (score 0):

As  Ian4264 and JaMiT mentioned, the first time you enter the loop, you make a new node and make `curr` point to it. Immediately after this you set `curr` to `curr->next` and it points to some arbitrary location. You never set `curr->next` point to this location where you'll make further allocations.

```
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* addTwoNumbers(ListNode* l1, ListNode* l2) {
        bool carry = 0;
        ListNode *head1 = l1; 
        ListNode *head2 = l2; 

        ListNode *head = nullptr;
        ListNode *curr = nullptr;

        while (head1 || head2 || carry) {
            // get value
            int val = (head1 ? head1->val : 0) +
                (head2 ? head2->val : 0) + carry;


            if (!curr){
                //first time around the loop (curr is nullptr) 
                //set curr to point to a new node
                curr = new ListNode(val % 10);
            }
            else {
                //if current was pointing to some node already, then 
                //its's next is set to point to the new allocation and curr
                //is set to the last node (just allocated) - and thus 
                //current
                curr->next = new ListNode(val % 10);
                curr = curr->next;
            }
            if (!head) head = curr;

            head1 = head1 ? head1->next : nullptr; 
            head2 = head2 ? head2->next : nullptr;
            carry = val / 10;
        }

        return head;
    }
};
```

Comment: `curr->next` might be null instead of an arbitrary location. We would need the constructor of `ListNode` to differentiate those cases.

Comment: @JaMiT Good point. Thanks for pointing out. But, if it were set to `nullptr`, wouldn't the assignment `curr = new ListNode(val % 10);` crash ?

Comment: Why would it crash? That line does not try to dereference `curr->next`, nor does it try to dereference `curr`.

Comment: Oops! yes, that's true.